# Query Hashes in Redis by date

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

The model that is being saved in Redis contains two date fields- startdate and enddate. I have inserted all data in hashes. More than 10K.
How can I efficiently query with both date fields as parameters. For now I bring all hashes from the db, deserialize them and query the results. Not efficient but works for the test. Was wondering how to achieve this the best way. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis isn't designed to be *queryable*. You need to store the data in the way you want to be later required from the application layer.

For example, if you want to get your models in ascending order by *startdate*, then you need to store your models' identifiers in a *sorted set* providing the *startdate* as an integer and it will be used as sorted set item *score*.

If you want to get your models with more complex criterias, you'll need to scratch your mind to calculate scores based on more than a model property to store them in other sorted sets.

Later, you'll be able to get ranges (`zrange`, `zrevrange`...) of these ordered identifiers to pass them to an `hmget` command which will get all values for the given identifiers.

You need to think about Redis like an index of indexes. It's about indexing your data to retrieve it efficiently.